# regex - all numbers that are not after "-", ".", "/"

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm using this regex to extract all the numbers from a string.

```
([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

I'm trying to change it so numbers that are coming after the characters "." "-" "/" won't be return.

I tried

```
[^-.]([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

or

```
^[^-.]+$([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**Edit2**

Example.
I have this text:

```
 7
.7
-7
/7
-12 123

12,2

22.22
```

I want the regex to return the the groups 123 12,2 and 22.22

Comment: So, what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: Could you please describe your problem more precisely, maybe with a text and the matches you'd like to find?

Comment: Do u want this? https://regex101.com/r/qocZza/1

Comment: @Mr.kang, probably, but javascript is used... :)

Comment: @Mr.kang FYI: This does not work in JavaScript. Negative Lookbehinds do not work in JavaScript. JavaScript's implementation of Regex _sucks_. Thought I should mention that because JavaScipt was tagged.

Comment: @Mr.kang, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @LarsH No, because it's not an answer. As others have pointed out it uses a feature which isn't available in JavaScript.

Comment: I would still say it is an answer, but you're right that it's probably not worth posting, now that the incompatibility has been pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
/(?:^|[^-.\/\d])([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)/g
```

The first part means "start of string or a character which isn't `.`, `/` or `-` (in a non captured group). I added `\d` in that group to avoid capturing starting from the second digit of a number which shouldn't be captured.

**Demonstration (and a way to use it):**

```js
var results = [],
    regex = /(?:^|[^-.\/\d])([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)/g,
    text = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML,
    m;
while (m=regex.exec(text)) {
  results.push(m[1]);
 }
document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(results);
```

```html
<p>123,456 -12 123 some text. 2258 a.666 36,45 a/123 999 22.22</p>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I think it's perfect. Give me few minutes to check it out and i'll approve it. Thanks

Comment: I see your updated question. My answer wouldn't find 22.22 for example. Let me edit it. edit: done

Comment: I edited my answer. Now that the idea should be clear, I suggest you use my approach with an extensive text to check everything and if necessary adapt it.

Comment: Amazing. will do. 
Thanks!